# Get data from swf

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I have a swf video player file, exactly like the one on this [url](https://www.yoklan.com/sportstream-365.html)

In this swf file, it first gets some event list from somewhere and i am trying to find this url so that i can get it with php or javascript or any type of external way...

I decompiled it with JPEXS and can see in logs that it is trying to get some data from rtmpe://ip_address/xsportzone but i am not sure if this is correct or how i can get same data from outsite...

I would appreciate any kind of help...

Comment: Do you have any code that isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: Right now i dont have anything, i just decompiled swf and saw rtmpe://ip_address/xsportzone but i am not even sure that it is the right url... Even if it is right url i dont know how to use it... Right now i am trying to find resources or sample codes to show me what to do...

Comment: So, there's a client-server application. You, somehow, laid your hands on client part, but you cannot get server because it is, well, server. You should probably take it as a sign from the universe to stop stealing someone's work and learn to do things on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your useless comment... This is a public application without any copyrights, they are streaming sports event globally from their website and this application, they also allow adding these streams to your website free of charge since they are already adding some ads and odds to stream itself... There is nothing illegal or wrong with i am asking...

Comment: rtmpe is encrypted stream and only macromedia flash can play it. is Nothing you can do this app is well encrypted.